# Reviewing Close Votes

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I've been reviewing close votes that don't seem to fit any of the available categories for voting to close.  The questions are reasonably good, there's enough background, they don't need to go to ELL (although they might have been welcome there in the first place).  What **has** happened is that they've been briefly and pertinently answered (in comments) by one or two (or four or five) people, the OP has said "thanks", and there's really nothing more to say.  As closed, they remain re-openable in the event someone wants to pose a more comprehensive answer.  But they're complete, helpful, and finished as they stand.  What about adding a reason like "Taken care of", "Fully Handled," "You can put a fork in me, I'm done."

Would something like "close because complete" work? Or "We're finished here" or "We Be Done" or "That's All Folks"

Comment: Could you please provide  links  to the questions you are referring to?

Comment: Here's a list of a few: Close as Complete?.....
Meaning of “side”.....
POS of the word “what”.....
Is “to climb” phraseological in common speech?.....
Are the changes in the following text necessary/preferred?.....
Is there any word containing Q but not followed by U.....

Comment: Closing isn't like putting a folder aside or closing a case, it's forbidding further work on a project we're working on that's gone wrong until we figure out a way to fix it, or throw the project in the trash. So your suggestion frankly doesn't make much sense. If a question's been answered in the comments, you can either tell the comment-answerer to write an answer of their own -- which, BTW, usually doesn't work -- or adding a community wiki answer, quoting the commentator. That's the closest thing you get to a 'case closed'.

Comment: Actually I am suggesting no further work--on matters that appear to be minor, fully handled, and not worth further time and attention--even if the questions have been good and the comments as well.

Comment: Please provide a link to each of your examples.   It is not practical to find your examples without a link to each one.

Comment: Thank you all for your points of view.

Answer (score 6):

[Help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) explains:

> Closing is a democratic voting process where the community identifies questions that duplicate existing content, are unreasonable to answer in their current state, or do not belong on the site.

When reviewing a question from the [Close Votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close) queue, regardless of what partial or complete answers you see in the comments, judge the question solely on its merits, and if it is close-worthy, close it, or if not, don't.

If you notice an on-topic question poorly worded, tagged or formatted, edit to improve it.

If you need closure for a (clearly on-topic) question in the other sense, that is, a sense of resolution or completion, to save it from forever zombieing around in the '[unanswered](https://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered)' list, you can:

1. Properly answer it, while taking advantage of all relevant information available in the comments under it, and [adding sugar, spice and everything nice](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to make your answer genuinely yours, and give credit where it's due.
2. Make a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/309993) answer, where you simply quote the most useful parts of the partial (or complete) answers given in the comments, which becomes a great answer somehow, and it is simply a courtesy, not a rule, to not grab reputation off of it.
3. Request the users who answered in the comments to make a proper answer, and forever wait for them to really care.

Good on-topic questions will always remain open, to welcome new answers with more information.

Getting answers 'accepted' under questions from new users is a rare sight, as most of them would simply read some answers and be on their way and never return.

Comment: Can mods accept answers on behalf of users, if they do zombie around after an answer?

Comment: @marcellothearcane No. And why would that be an option? 'Accepted' means that that answer was most useful to the OP. An accepted answer may be wrong, and OPs may still accept it.

Comment: Say a zombie question gets asked, answered in the comments, re-answered in a community wiki, but left (say the OP turns into a zombie themself). Or is *accepting* not the issue (just *answering*)?

Comment: @marcellothearcane You should ask a new meta question. I can't explain well in the comments.

Comment: go ahead :) https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/can-mods-accept-answers-on-anothers-behalf

Answer (score 5):

Your suggestion completely goes against the principles of Stack Exchange. Questions are here to stay and if somebody thinks they can provide a better answer than the existing ones, they should always be able to do so without going through the process of reopening the question first. In contrast to many forums, we do not have a problem with old questions being revived for this purpose – there are even badges for this. Questions being solved is indicated by accepted answers.

Closing on the other hand is intended for questions where answers cause problems, e.g., because we cannot objectively vote on them (primarily opinion-based, strictly off-topic), there are too many of them, or they are too long (too broad), they create redundancy or fragmented information (duplicate).

People answering questions in a comment is a problem, but none that we should take care of by closing said questions.

Answer (score 5):

Many questions that are answered only in comments ought to be closed because of the already existing close reasons. Many of these are closed eventually; some are not.  I often answer a question in a comment to help the OP and then immediately VTC.

For a user to VTC a *good* question because its comments seem to him to be

> complete, helpful, and finished as they stand

is....I wish I could think of a kinder word....arrogant.  Just because ***I*** can't think of anything to add to a set of comments doesn't mean that there isn't some aspect I have not thought of (and don't know enough to think of) that could be addressed.  Moreover, we are always hearing that comments are ephemeral; only answers are permanent.  Thus, a question is not answered until it has an Answer.  Then, logically, if one has a VTC reason "completed", that should apply to a question which has been completely answered by one or more Answers.  Ergo, our aim is to get every question on this site to the point where it can be closed as completed? I think not.